# Comment dire «free software» en français?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, informatique

Il y a beaucoup de logiciels qui se présentent comme un logiciel «free». «Free», dans ce cas, ne représente pas simplement le mot gratuit. Bien que le logiciel est gratuit, le logiciel est aussi libre, parce que, comme les programmeurs l'expliquent, le logiciel ne peut pas être vraiment «free» si l'utilisateur ne peut pas voir le code source du logiciel. L'idée du logiciel «free» en anglais est un jeu de mots, parce qu'il indique deux sens. Donc, est-ce qu'il y a un mot ou une phrase que je peux utiliser pour exprimer le même sens en français?

Comment: Je trouve que ce message est hors sujet ici car il concerne les us et coutumes - les rites, devrais-je dire - du monde informatique. C'est une "question" mille fois posée, ritournelle propre à ces personnes, avec réponses convenues d'avance... Donc je mets -1 :-) Cordialement, et bienvenue sur ce forum tout de même :-)

Comment: « l'idée du logiciel « free » en anglais est un jeu de mots, parce qu'il indique deux sens. » Pourquoi alors passent-ils donc tant de temps à insister que c'est « free as in free speech, not in free beer » ?

Comment: @Istao Pourquoi ? C'est du vocabulaire technique.

Comment: @Gilles : non ce sont des redites ; cela fait 30 ans que les gens du logiciel libre parlent et reparlent là dessus... la seule "nouveauté" a été quand la société française "free" est appparue, ça a renouvelé les buzz(s?) :-) ...un des 1 million de discours sur le sujet : http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.fr.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En fait, l'expression *free software* en anglais a fait couler beaucoup d'encre (ou au moins beaucoup d'électrons) justement parce qu'elle est ambiguë à cause du double sens de l'adjectif *free*. En français, on utilise des mots différents pour ces deux sens : *gratuit* signifie que l'on n'a pas à payer (*free as in free beer*), *libre* signifie que l'on peut en faire ce qu'on veut ou presque (*free as in free speech*). C'est au point qu'on dit quelquefois *libre software* en anglais pour parler de logiciel libre.

« Logiciel libre » est l'expression consacrée pour traduire l'expression *free software* dans le sens d'*open source*. Elle s'est popularisée dans les années 1990 en même temps que Linux. Je ne sais pas qui l'a inventée (Richard Stallman, peut-être, puisqu'il parle français ?) ni s'il y a eu une volonté consciente de l'introduire ; la construction est naturelle en français. La plus ancienne occurrence que je trouve sur [Google Books](http://www.google.fr/search?q=%22logiciel+libre%22&btnG=Chercher+des+livres) est date de [1989](http://books.google.fr/books?id=n5UwRqz7UeoC&dq=%22logiciel+libre%22) (pour parler de Scilab, qui n'est pas un logiciel libre au sens actuel et qui je crois ne l'était pas à l'époque, mais dont le source était disponible — cela dit, c'était avant que les théories modernes sur ce qui constituent un logiciel libre soient bien établies).

Si la question est de traduire l'ambiguïté de « *free software* », c'est difficile. Je doute qu'on puisse faire mieux que « logiciel gratuit », ce qui ne dit pas si le logiciel est aussi libre ou non.

Comment: Bonne réponse, "logiciel libre". Mais, garder l’ambiguïté n'a aucun intérêt et est un problème de l'anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne sais pas si c'est accepté en France, mais je sais qu'au Canada le terme « gratuiciel » est accepté comme traduction directe de *freeware*.

Comment: Jamais entendu en France ou en Belgique. L'information est très intéressante, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Au Québec le terme utilisé est "logiciel libre".

Answer (score 0):

Logiciel libre suffit, à l'utilisateur de définir l’étendue de la gratuité.
Merci à Gilles pour l'historique, cependant, les mentions légales sont là pour lever l’ambiguïté relevée.